# Magento 2 : Undefined Index : Default

Tags: magento2, admin, theme

In Backend When I try to change theme at that time I got this error

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: default in /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/project/app/code/Codazon/ThemeOptions/Framework/App/Config/Initial.php on line 72
```

**`Initial.php`**

```
public function getData($scope)
    {

        list($scopeType, $scopeId) = array_pad(explode('|', $scope), 2, null);
        $this->themeId = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(\Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface::XML_PATH_THEME_ID,$scopeType,$scopeId);
        $cacheKey = self::CACHE_ID.'|theme|'.$this->themeId;
        $data = $this->cache->load($cacheKey);
        if (!$data) {
            $data = $this->reader->read($this->themeId);
            $this->cache->save(serialize($data), $cacheKey);
        } else {
            $data = unserialize($data);
        }
        if($data){
            $this->_data = $data['data'];
            $this->_metadata = $data['metadata'];
        }
        return $this->_data['default'];
    }
```

Comment: You havent display default anywhere in your code, so remove default from $this->data['default'] and set  return as  only $this->_data;

Comment: can you guys look at this issue?  thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297085/notice-undefined-index-default-in-vendor-magento-module-catalog-batchsiz

Answer (score 1):

You havent display default anywhere in your code, so remove default from

> $this->data['default']

and set return as only

> $this->_data;

– Rakesh May 1 at 5:26

this resolved my issue

Comment: can you guys look at this issue?  thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297085/notice-undefined-index-default-in-vendor-magento-module-catalog-batchsiz